# How i can monitor Http hits using mrtg?

Tags: linux, monitoring, redhat, mrtg

Greetings ...

How i can monitor Http hits using mrtg on linux server (RedHat) ? and what are the requirements for that process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to activate mod_status within your Apache instance. 
For a good explanation visit http://www.linux-sottises.net/en_mrtg.php and use the scripts provided there.